# Solving Linear Algebra Equation for Matrix Power

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck trying to solve a matrix equation for a power of a matrix. If $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a 2x2 matrix, and $\boldsymbol{x}$ is a 2 x 1 vector, I have the equation:

$\boldsymbol{A}^s \boldsymbol{x} = 0.5 \boldsymbol{x}$

I get stuck because $\boldsymbol{x}$ is a 2 x 1 vector and can't be divided (so far as I know). I've tried various things:

1) multiply both sides by $\boldsymbol{x'}$ to convert to a 2x2 matrix:

$\boldsymbol{A}^s \boldsymbol{xx'} = 0.5 \boldsymbol{xx'}$

if $\boldsymbol{xx'} = \boldsymbol{M}$

$\boldsymbol{A}^s \boldsymbol{M} = 0.5 \boldsymbol{M}$

$\boldsymbol{A}^s \boldsymbol{M} \boldsymbol{M}^{-1} = 0.5 \boldsymbol{M} \boldsymbol{M}^{-1}$

$\boldsymbol{A}^s = 0.5 \boldsymbol{I}$

but that can't be right because $\boldsymbol{A}^s$ is not a diagonal matrix of constant 0.5.

2) Diagonalize $\boldsymbol{A}$

$\boldsymbol{A}^s \boldsymbol{x} = 0.5 \boldsymbol{x}$

$\boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{D}^s \boldsymbol{P}^{-1} \boldsymbol{x} = 0.5 \boldsymbol{x}$

$\boldsymbol{D}^s \boldsymbol{P}^{-1} \boldsymbol{x} = 0.5 \boldsymbol{P}^{-1}  \boldsymbol{x}$

but that can't be right because it implies that $\boldsymbol{D}^s$ is a scalar.

I'm not sure that what I'm trying to do is even possible or makes any sense. I know it works in standard form:

$\theta^s x = 0.5 x$

$\theta^s = 0.5$

$s \log \theta = \log 0.5$

$s = \log 0.5 / \log \theta$

but I can't make it work in matrix form. Thoughts?

UPDATE
I'm pursuing the second approach, and here's where I get stuck.

$\boldsymbol{D}^s = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1^s & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2^s\end{bmatrix}$

$\boldsymbol{P}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} p_{11} & p_{12} \\ p_{21} & p_{22} \end{bmatrix}$

$\boldsymbol{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ x_1 \end{bmatrix}$

Note that this is actually the form of $\boldsymbol{x}$ I'm working with.

Then

$\boldsymbol{P}^{-1}\boldsymbol{x} = \begin{bmatrix} p_{12} x_1 \\ p_{22} x_1 \end{bmatrix}$

So you wind up with with

$\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1^s p_{12} x_1 \\ \lambda_2^s p_{22} x_1 \end{bmatrix}$ = 
$\begin{bmatrix} 0.5 p_{12} x_1 \\ 0.5 p_{22} x_1 \end{bmatrix}$

If you solve those two equations separately for $s$, you get

$\lambda_1^s p_{12} x_1 = 0.5 p_{12} x_1$

$s \log \lambda_1 = \log 0.5$, $s =  \log 0.5 / \log \lambda_1$

and

$\lambda_2^s p_{12} x_1 = 0.5 p_{12} x_1$

$s \log \lambda_2 = \log 0.5$, $s =  \log 0.5 / \log \lambda_2$

The only way this seems possible is if $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$. I must be off here.

Comment: Your second approach is a good one. However your implication that $D^t$ is a scalar is wrong. It just acts on the vector like a scalar.

Comment: You could multiply both sides by the inverse of A-transpose.

Comment: @maxmilgram I don't think I understand. $\boldsymbol{D}^t$ is a diagonal matrix with two different eigenvalues: $\lambda_1^t$ and $\lambda_2^t$. So those both can't be equal to 0.5, right?

Comment: For anyone who might be thinking $A^t$ is referring to $A$-transpose, it is not here. It is referring to "$A$ to the power $t$", and $t$ is some number. Maybe good to change $t$ to $s$ or something.

Comment: Ah good point, thanks.

Comment: What do you want to know? $A$ or $x$?

Comment: I'm trying to find $s$

Comment: Ahh ok! I can help u, wait.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help you:

Let $\boldsymbol{A}$ be a matrix and $det(\boldsymbol{A})\neq0$
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} =  \lambda \boldsymbol{x}
\end{equation}
Where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalues and $\boldsymbol{x}$ an eigenvector, then:

\begin{eqnarray}
\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x} &=& \boldsymbol{A}\lambda \boldsymbol{x}\\
\boldsymbol{A}^{2}\boldsymbol{x} &=& \lambda \boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}\\
\boldsymbol{A}^{2}\boldsymbol{x} &=& \lambda^{2} \boldsymbol{x}
\end{eqnarray}

Repeating this indefinitely, we have:

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{A}^{s}\boldsymbol{x} = \lambda^{s}\boldsymbol{x}
\end{equation}

In this particular case $\lambda^{s} = 0.5$, then:

\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda^{s}&=&\boldsymbol{x}\\
s&=&log_{\lambda}(0.5)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: right, but i amended my answer above because $x$ is not an eigenvector here.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are correct.

Essentially you have two equations here and one variable. Thus, it is to be expected that the system can only be solved for special choices of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{A}$.